# How to pass a Dictionary variable to another procedure

Tags: c#, dictionary, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008

I am developing a C# VS2008/SQL Server website application.  I've never used the Dictionary class before, but I am trying to replace my Hashtable with a Dictionary variable.

Here is a portion of my aspx.cs code:

```
...
Dictionary<string, string> openWith = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 

for (int col = 0; col < headers.Length; col++)
{
   @temp = (col + 1);
   @tempS = @temp.ToString();
   @tempT = "@col" + @temp.ToString();
   ...
   openWith.Add(@tempT, headers[col]);
}
...
for (int r = 0; r < myInputFile.Rows.Count; r++)
 { resultLabel.Text = ADONET_methods.AppendDataCT(myInputFile, openWith); }
```

But this is giving me a compiler error on this last line:
Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' to 'string'

How do I pass the entire openWith variable to AppendDataCT?  AppendDataCT is the method that calls my SQL stored proc.  I want to pass in the whole row where each row has a unique set of values that I want to add to my database table.  For example, if each row requires values for cells A, B, and C, then I want to pass these 3 values to AppendDataCT, where all of these values are strings.  How do I do this with Dictionary?

Comment: extract from dictionary and pass as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is not your dictionary and its not how you are passing it. the problem is your method `AppendDataCT`, it is expecting a `string` parameter, not a `dictionary<string,string>`

assuming this, you probably want something kinda like this....

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<string,string> item in openWith )
{
    resultLabel.Text = ADONET_methods.AppendDataCT(myInputFile, item.Value);
}
```

this will iterate over your dictionary, and for every pair of [key,value]
call your AppendDataCT method, using the value from the pair.