# How do I access Dictionary items?

Tags: c#, dictionary, visual-studio-2008

I am developing a C# VS2008 / SQL Server website app and am new to the Dictionary class.  Can you please advise on best method of accomplishing this?  Here is a code snippet:

```
SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(connString);
SqlCommand cmd = conn2.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.AppendDataCT";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = conn2;
SqlParameter p1, p2, p3;
foreach (string s in dt.Rows[1].ItemArray)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[1]; // second row
    p1 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue((string)dic[0], (string)dr[0]);
    p1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
    p2 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue((string)dic[1], (string)dr[1]);
    p2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
    p3 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue((string)dic[2], (string)dr[2]);
    p3.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
}
```

but this is giving me compiler error:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,string>.this[string]' has some invalid arguments
```

I just want to access each value from "dic" and load into these SQL parameters.  How do I do this?  Do I have to enter the key?  The keys are named "col1", "col2", etc., so not the most user-friendly.  Any other tips?  Thanks!

Comment: this is a duplicate, you asked this twice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a Dictionary variable to another procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987142/how-to-pass-a-dictionary-variable-to-another-procedure)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be trying to access a `Dictionary<string, string>` by *integer* index. You can't do that - you have to look up the value by the key, which is a string.

If you don't want to use string keys, why are you using a `Dictionary<string, string>` to start with? Could you either use a `List<string>` or a `Dictionary<int, string>`?

Note that once you *have* managed to use the indexer appropriately, you won't need to cast to string.

Answer (score 30):

A `Dictionary` maps objects of one type into objects of another type. In your case you've got a `Dictionary<string, string>`. So if you had it initialised like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
   { "key1", "value1" },
   { "key2", "value2" },
   { "key3", "value3" }
};
```

You'd get the value for `key2` by doing

```
dic["key2"]; // gives "value2"
```

The `Dictionary` is strongly-typed, so there's no need for any casting. As Jon Skeet says, you may be better off with a `List<string>` here. You can access these by the integer index.

Comment: this should be the answer. the given answer is bad

Answer (score 3):

Here's a piece of code that will do what you're after, I think.. You will have to add in an else statement, but it should get you started.

```
public void AttachParam(ref DbCommand command, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
  try
  {
     if (parameters.Count > 0)
     {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in parameters)
        {
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
     }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     throw;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your keys are "col1", "col2", etc then using 0, 1, etc will cause the error you're getting. Try this:

```
p1 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(dic["col1"], dr[0]);
p1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
p2 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(dic["col2"], dr[1]);
p2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
p3 = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(dic["col3"], dr[2]);
p3.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
```

Also, there is no need to cast to `string` as the dictionary object will return strings already.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand what really you are looking for, so here is my small advice.
There is a way to browse dictionary by not requesting items by key. It's a foreach option.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> pair in dic)
{
    p. = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(dic.Value /*or dic.Key*/, (string)dr[0]);
    p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
    // further processing of this parameter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes values must be accessed by the key.